# How do I display Today and Yesterday using date?

Tags: php, jquery, date

I am fetching data from the database. Now I have a date which is below

```
`2019-03-10 04:50:26`
`2019-03-09 01:30:55`
`2019-03-08 16:22:45`
```

What I am doing is, If the date is today's date then "`Today`" if the date is yesterday date then display "`Yesterday`" else display actual date.

My expected output is

```
Today | Sunday

Yesterday | Saturday

8th March 2019 | Friday
```

I tried below code.

```
$nofiDate=date('jS F Y', strtotime($result->created_added)); // getting `8th March 2019`
$day = date('l', strtotime($result->created_added)); // getting days name "Friday"
```

using the above code I am getting output is `8th March 2019 | Friday`

but how do I display today and Yesterday using date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert a time today and yesterday to date strings in the same format that you're using. Then compare with them, and replace with the words you want.

```
$today = date("jS F Y");
$yesterday = date("jS F Y", time() - 86400); // 86400 seconds in a day
```

Then you can compare `$nofiDate` with those, and show the strings you want instead:

```
if ($nofiDate == $today) {
    $nofiDate = "Today";
} elseif ($nofiDate == $yesterday) {
    $nofiDate = "Yesterday";
}
```

Comment: Give me some time to check

Answer (score 1):

You need to do if else comparison, if date is equal today date then assign variable $day = 'Today' else if subtracted by one day must be Yesterday
This code should work

```
    if($day==date('l')){
       $day = 'Today';
    }else if(date('l',  now() - (24 * 60 * 60))){
       $day = 'Yesterday';
    }
```

Comment: He wants to replace the full date with these strings, but keep the day of week.

Comment: Your code will also show "Today" for the same day in a different week.